# Geolocation Extension showing white map

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, geolocation

I recently installed an extension to firefox (the only compatible browser) so that I could change the location the browser viewed me in.

It's called [Geolocater](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/geolocater/) and it allows you to change which country your browsing from. I was using it fine earlier but I hadn't gotten used to how it worked yet. 
I'm not sure if that is the cause of my problem but now Geolocate wont open from the "Tools" section of my browser, and when I open it from the extensions section it will open with a white screen (used to have a map of the globe) and I can't add or edit geolocations (I couldn't earlier).

Is there any way to fix this and does this fall under software support? (For Super User)

Imgur Rejected me of sending a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I tried this earlier but it mustn't have saved. You have to enable geo.enabled in about:config .